# GUI Trouble reading JTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I can't figure out where I am going wrong with this,  I have tried to changing a few  things but I just can't get the "CalculateButtonHandler to work correctly.  Sorry put out all this code but last time I wasn't specific enough :S  If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.  Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

// some kind of problem with Calculate button handler (LINE 78 

public class Program5 extends JFrame
{
    // Setting up for the program
    private JLabel side1, side2, side3, str, result;

    private JButton calculate, endProgram;

    private JTextField input1, input2, input3;

    private CalculateButtonHandler calcHandler;
    private EndProgramButtonHandler endHandler;

    private Container pane;

    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 350;

    // constructor
    public Program5()
    {
        // create labels
        side1 = new JLabel ("Triangle's Longest Side: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        side2 = new JLabel ("Triangle's Next Side: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        side3 = new JLabel ("Triangle's Last Side: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        result = new JLabel ("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        str = new JLabel ("Is the Triangle a right Triangle?",SwingConstants.CENTER);

        // create text fields
        input1 = new JTextField ("", 60);
        input1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        input2 = new JTextField ("", 60);
        input2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        input3 = new JTextField ("", 60);
        input3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        // create buttons
        calculate = new JButton ("Calculate");
        calcHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler ();
        calculate.addActionListener(calcHandler);

        endProgram = new JButton ("Exit");
        endHandler = new EndProgramButtonHandler();
        endProgram.addActionListener(endHandler);

        // Set title of Window
        setTitle ("Right Triangle Tester");

        //Get Container
        pane = getContentPane();

        // set Layout
        pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (5, 2));

        // place the components in the pane
        pane.add(side1);
        pane.add(input1);
        pane.add(side2);
        pane.add(input2);
        pane.add(side3);
        pane.add(input3);
        pane.add(str);
        pane.add(result);
        pane.add(calculate);
        pane.add(endProgram);

        // set size of the window and display it
        setSize (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setVisible (true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
    }

    private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            double num1, num2, num3;
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(side1.getText());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(side2.getText());
            num3 = Double.parseDouble(side3.getText());

            if ((num1*num1) == ((num2*num2)+(num3*num3)))
            {
                result.setText("YES");
            }
            else
            {
            result.setText("NO");
            }
        }       
    }

    private class EndProgramButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {       
        Program5 myObject = new Program5();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "work correctly" and "work incorrectly". What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing the sideX text which are the JLabels and not your JTextFields. Replace the sideX by inputX in your `CalculateButtonHandler` and all will be fine

Comment: +1, seems like I refreshed my page too late, your answer came way to earlier on this. Nice catch, I spend time giving the whole output.

Comment: WHOA do I feel dumb.  After looking at my code for a few hours what a stupid mistake,  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) use [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) (witt `Number instance`) rather than plain [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), then you couldn't ever to solving parsing `Number` instance from `String`,

2) looks like this code parse text from [JLabels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) instead of `JTextFields`

Comment: +1, for the nice catch, I was too late on submitting the whole answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your `CalculateButtonHandler` class you using `JLabel` to get input, seems like you need JTextField to get input for that, change that class to this :

```
private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        double num1, num2, num3;
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText());
        num3 = Double.parseDouble(input3.getText());

        if ((num1*num1) == ((num2*num2)+(num3*num3)))
        {
            result.setText("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            result.setText("NO");
        }
    }       
}
```

And From next time always Schedule a JOB for the Event Dispatcher Thread, while using Swing like in your case your main method must look like this :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

// some kind of problem with Calculate button handler (LINE 78 

public class Program5 extends JFrame
{
    // Setting up for the program
    private JLabel side1, side2, side3, str, result;

    private JButton calculate, endProgram;

    private JTextField input1, input2, input3;

    private CalculateButtonHandler calcHandler;
    private EndProgramButtonHandler endHandler;

    private Container pane;

    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 350;

    // constructor
    public Program5()
    {
            // create labels
        side1 = new JLabel ("Triangle's Longest Side: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        side2 = new JLabel ("Triangle's Next Side: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        side3 = new JLabel ("Triangle's Last Side: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        result = new JLabel ("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        str = new JLabel ("Is the Triangle a right Triangle?",SwingConstants.CENTER);


            // create text fields
        input1 = new JTextField ("",60);
        input1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        input2 = new JTextField ("",60);
        input2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        input3 = new JTextField ("",60);
        input3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        // create buttons
        calculate = new JButton ("Calculate");
        calcHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler ();
        calculate.addActionListener(calcHandler);

        endProgram = new JButton ("Exit");
        endHandler = new EndProgramButtonHandler();
        endProgram.addActionListener(endHandler);

        // Set title of Window
        setTitle ("Right Triangle Tester");

        //Get Container
        pane = getContentPane();

        // set Layout
        pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (5,2));

        // place the components in the pane
        pane.add(side1);
        pane.add(input1);
        pane.add(side2);
        pane.add(input2);
        pane.add(side3);
        pane.add(input3);
        pane.add(str);
        pane.add(result);
        pane.add(calculate);
        pane.add(endProgram);

        // set size of the window and display it
        setSize (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        se1tVisible (true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    }

    private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            double num1, num2, num3;
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText());
            num3 = Double.parseDouble(input3.getText());

            if ((num1*num1) == ((num2*num2)+(num3*num3)))
            {
                result.setText("YES");
            }
            else
            {
                result.setText("NO");
            }
        }       
    }

    private class EndProgramButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        // Here this is used to attain Concurrency in Swing.
        // So that if there is a need to update the GUI, 
        // that can be done without any difficulty or freezing the GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Program5 myObject = new Program5();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To know more about what I am talking about read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Very Important thing about Swing is on this Chapter.

Comment: I originally had my calculate as a JTextField, but it still wasn't reading.  I don't understand what the "SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnables()) is (I will have to look into that a little later today)  But the error I get in eclipse is says something about AWT-EventQue-0 and then goes on to talk about floatingDecimals (I am still figuring out how to debug in eclipse)  Have I set up the num1 num2 num3 correctly?

Comment: @ChewOnThis_Trident : Give me 2 mins, I be posting your code with the needed changes, that might can explain you things.

Answer (score 1):

You're also directly comparing doubles. It's very unlikely that you will get this comparison as true. Run this:

`double num1,num2,num3;
     num1=2.8284271247461903;   //== Math.sqrt(8) 
     num2=2.0; num3=2.0;
     if ((num1*num1) == ((num2*num2)+(num3*num3)))
         System.out.println  ("yes");
     else System.out.println  ("no " + num1*num1 + " " + (num2*num2 + num3*num3));`

}

Comment: +1, no doubt a food for thoughts, I had upvoted this a long time back though.